# Polynomial Regression with grouped independent observations

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, polynomial, diagnostic

I am trying to model how porosity changes across burn up levels of a fuel pellet. I have 300 observations at varying levels of burn up. The way my data is collected makes burn up appear as a categorical variable, but I'm interested in the continuous relationship.

The cubic relationship makes sense in theory but not sure if it's appropriate given model diagnostics and available data.

[image]

[image]

Is there a different approach I should take with this data? Obviously variances are unequal across burn up, not quite sure the appropriate generalized linear model for a situation like this. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given x just has 5 distinct values, it is hard to treat x as continue variable. Your interesting can not change the fact that x just has 5 unique values.

Comment: Could you post the data, or a link to the data?